# Understanding the way a figure is drawn

Tags: c, image, graphics, drawing, draw

[image]

This is the result drawing out of the following mysterious code that evidently draws everything pixel by pixel on a canvas area:

```
int w, h;

for(w = 0; w < width; w++)
{
    for(h = height-1; h >= 0; h--)
    {
        setpen(w, h, distance(w, h, 255, 255), 0.0F, 1U); // r g b(distance wh : 255) transp pensize
        putpixel(w, h);
    }
}
```

---

How come such a short code can result in such an interesting image?
Does it have a name? Purposes? What does it present at all?

Comment: The short code is using the `distance` function, which is doing most of the work.

Comment: Perhaps yes.. but what happens behind the code is kinda curious though. And the result.. can't figure it out.

Comment: It is nice. But I don't see much of question here. Mandelbrot fractal code is fairly simple as well.

Comment: The comment shows that red and green come from x and y coordinate. For blue, you'll need to look at the function `distance()`, but it's a fair guess to suppose that blue comes from radial distance and is cropped at 255. The image size is 514x514, with a border of 1 that is 512 by 512. So the colours suffer a step change as the coordinate passes from 255 to 256 (mod 256).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mystery here, as analysis of the image and a little observation show.

Firstly, the image size is 514 x 514, removing the border this gives the effective size as 512 x 512.

The comment in the code at `setpen()` indicates the first three arguments set the colour levels of red, green and blue. The next is transparency, set to 0. The last argument is pen size, set to 1 so no pixel written will affect any neighbour.

Ignoring the blue component for now, the red and green arguments are passed the pixel coordinates. Since the colour range is 0..255 and the coordinate range is 0..511, red and green will each "wrap" twice to produce four identical tiles. Each of the tiles (as you can see) will fade from red (255,0,b) to green (0,255,b) along one diagonal, and from black (0,0,b) to yellow (255,255,b) along the other diagonal. Where each tile joins, the coordinate passes from 255 to 256, making the colour value step from 255 to 0.

Now let's add blue. My eyes tell me that the blue component increases radially outward from the centre, and again there is a step change at radius 256. I detect a hint of dark blue at the top left corner of the image (where is should be black), and using the "dropper" tool in a graphics utility shows that the blue level in the very corner is 104.

So now I will reverse-engineer the `distance` function.

```
int distance(int x, int y, int ox, int oy) {
    int dx = x - ox;
    int dy = y - oy;
    return (int)sqroot(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

Now testing this to see what it returns at (0, 0)

```
dx = 0 - 255
dy = 0 - 255
return 360
```

Since the pixel colour will be `mod 256`, the `360` blue will be plotted as (360 - 256) = 104.

Finally, notice that the circle does not quite reach the border along the right and bottom edges, there is a 1-pixel wide strip. This is due to the fact that the circle centre was passed to `distance` as `255`, and the image size is an even number of pixels, so there is no exact centre.

QED

Comment: I decided to experiment a little bit and guess what came up if each of the values uses the distance function.

Comment: The other answer suggests using trig functions like `sin`, of course it will have to be `255 * sin(x)` with `x` scaled appropriately from `h`. Or perhaps `127 + 127*sin(x)`.

Comment: http://vegasoft.site90.com/drawing.png this appears when rgb obtains value from distance. While it looks identical, it appears that it simplifies the understanding as it makes it color independent.

Comment: Before I look I will take a guess: a greyscale image fading from black at the centre to white, with a circular step to black and the fading again towards white.

Comment: Almost exact. It fades from white at the center to black.

Comment: Not on the one I am looking at in your link: black at the centre.

Comment: Yes. The center is fully black. Oh you mean from black to center like Inside Out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84040/discussion-between-malina-and-weather-vane).

Comment: (Ignore the chat invitation) By the way for the sake of argument isn't `sqrt` the math function for square root ?

Comment: distance: Returns the distance between points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).
`double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)`

Answer (score 1):

This code draws one pixel at a time just as you noticed, and it is indeed a mystery as we do not have the content of the setpen, or the distance functions.

To understand how such a simple code could produce such a complex image you have to first remember that a function as simple as getPixelColor(x,y) could draw any possible image you could imagine by reading each pixel from a file. By hiding the details like this pictures of arbitrary complexity can be created with simple code.

This concept is quite important in computer science and is called "abstraction". What this means is that we hide the details of how pixel color is selected inside a function which is implemented elsewhere and accessed in a seemingly simple way.

If you wanted to draw different types of images you could just change the function which fetches each pixel and by doing this change between different images.

You could try to play with this by replacing the current functions with a function which sets the color using an equation - something like sin(x) for red, sin(y) for green and cos(x) for blue would give you a fairly interesting result with a pretty simple function.

Like somebody else mentioned you can also look into fractals. The Mandelbrot set is an interesting implementation where the equation to determine the pixel is similar to x=(x-1)^2+C.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MandelbrotSet.html